# MapStruct cannot find members from generic Set property

Tags: java, mapstruct

I started using MapStruct `1.4.0.CR1`. I'm also using Gradle:

```
dependencies {
  annotationProcessor("org.mapstruct:mapstruct-processor:${project.property("mapstruct.version")}")

  implementation("org.mapstruct:mapstruct:${project.property("mapstruct.version")}")
}
```

I have some JPA entities I'm trying to map:

```java
public class Exam implements Serializable {
  // More class members here

  @OneToMany(cascade = CascadeType.ALL, fetch = FetchType.LAZY, mappedBy = "exam", orphanRemoval = true)
  private Set<Scan> scans;

  public Exam() { } // ...no-argument constructor required by JPA

  public Exam(final Builder builder) {
    // ...set the rest also
    scans = builder.scans;
  }

  // getters (no setters), hashCode, equals, and builder here
}
```

```java
public class Scan implements Serializable {
  // More class members here

  @OneToMany(cascade = CascadeType.ALL, fetch = FetchType.LAZY, mappedBy = "scan", orphanRemoval = true)
  private Set<Alarm> alarms;

  @OneToMany(cascade = CascadeType.ALL, fetch = FetchType.LAZY, mappedBy = "scan", orphanRemoval = true)
  private Set<Isotope> isotopes;

  protected Scan() { } // ...no-argument constructor required by JPA

  public Scan(final Builder builder) {
    // ...set the rest also
    alarms = builder.alarms;
    isotopes = builder.isotopes;
  }

  // getters (no setters), hashCode, equals, and builder here
}
```

I have similar classes for mapping, but they don't have as many fields/members as the JPA entities, moreover, they are on a completely different sub-system (hence the mapping). The problem is that MapStruct is telling me there are no `isotopes` within `Scan`s: `java: No property named "scans.isotopes" exists in source parameter(s). Did you mean "scans.empty"?`.

Basically, `isotopes` and `alarms` are not contained within a `Set` of `scans` in the (new) mapped `Exam` class. This is my `ExamMapper`:

```java
@FunctionalInterface
@Mapper(componentModel = "spring", injectionStrategy = InjectionStrategy.CONSTRUCTOR)
public interface ExamMapper {
  // @Mapping(source = "scans.alarms", target = "alarms")
  @Mapping(source = "scans.isotopes", target = "isotopes")
  Exam valueFrom(tld.domain.Exam entity);
}
```

Is there a way to accomplish this? I think this may be trivial, but I'm fairly new to MapStruct ;)

Comment: what do the other Exam and Scan classes look like, you are trying to map to?

Comment: I don't need `Scan` on the mapped classes; I can update the question with those, but the important part is that the `Scan` set is gone in the mapped `Exam`, so the collections of `isotopes` and `alarms` become part/members of the new `Exam` class, but not within any other member (as it's initially).

Comment: ah I think I see whats going wrong here, the source parameter of the `Mapping` annotation must be the path inside the Parameter, you pass the method. In your case source would then be inside `tld.domain.Exam`

Comment: Indeed, that's what I thought also. Basically `tld.domain.Exam` is the one that contains `private Set<Scan> scans`, so I would expect `scans.isotopes` to work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `source` and `target` attributes of the `@Mapping` can only reference bean properties.

This means that when using `scans.isotopes`, it will look for a property `isotopes` in `Set<Scan>` and thus the compile error.

In order to solve this you'll need to provide some custom mappings. From what I can understand you will need to do flat mapping here as well. The reason for that is that you have multiple scans, and each scan has multiple isotopes. You need to gather all of that and map it into a single collection.

One way to achieve this is in the following way:

```
@Mapper(componentModel = "spring", injectionStrategy = InjectionStrategy.CONSTRUCTOR)
public interface ExamMapper {

  @Mapping(source = "scans", target = "isotopes")
  Exam valueFrom(tld.domain.Exam entity);

  Isotope valueFrom(tld.domain.Isotope isotope);

  default Set<Isotope> flatMapIsotopes(Set<Scan> scans) {
    return scans.stream()
        .flatMap(scan -> scan.getIsotopes().stream())
        .map(this::valueFrom)
        .collect(Collectors.toSet());
  }
 
}
```

Comment: Pixel perfect! Thanks for the tip!